# How to configure multi mongos instances access to a sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-shell

I couldn't find any clear document that explains how to config multi mongos instances in a single sharded cluster with numbers of shards. I want to have more mongos and assign them to numbers of application servers to reduce latency.

Answer (score 1):

You access a sharded cluster from a client via a `mongos` router.

Your cluster configuration can have many `mongos` routers (see [Number of mongos and
   Distribution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#number-of-mongos-and-distribution)). You connect from a client (e.g., a `mongo` shell) specifying multiple mongos's - and the client connects to the cluster using one of the `mongos`
(see: [Connecting to a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#connecting-to-a-sharded-cluster)).

From a `mongo` shell client you use a **connection string** to connect to a MongoDB server. To connect to a sharded cluster specify `mongos` host(s) in the connection string using [Standard ConnectionString Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format); an [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#sharded-cluster).